# Phone Number Generator ignoring user input

Tags: python, random

I'm quite new to Python.

```
#Amount of numbers wanting to be generated
numbers = str(int(input("How Many Numbers Do You Want To Generate: ")))
Number1 = int(numbers)
Number2 = int(numbers)
Number3 = int(numbers)

print("---------------------------------------------")

#generator values
gentype = "0123456789"

Telstra = "4001", "4002", "4003", "4004", "4005", "4006", "4007", "4008", "4009", "4601", "4609", "4800", "4901", "4909", "4910", "4914", "4920", "4929", "4070", "4079", "4080", "4089", "4090", "4099", "4170", "4179","4180", "4189", "4190", "4199", "4270", "4279", "4280", "4289", "4290", "4299", "4470", "4479", "4480", "4484", "4971", "4979", "4980", "4989", "4990", "4999"
Optus = "4010", "4019", "4020", "4029", "4030", "4039", "4110", "4119", "4120", "4129", "4130", "4139", "4810", "4819", "4340", "4349", "4350", "4359"
Vodafone = "test"

#generator code 
if carrier == "1": 
    for i in range(Number1):
     generatestarted1 = random.choice(Telstra)
     generatestarted2 = random.choice(gentype)
     generatestarted3 = random.choice(gentype)
     generatestarted4 = random.choice(gentype)
     generatestarted5 = random.choice(gentype)
     generatestarted6 = random.choice(gentype)
     generatestarted = ("+61"+generatestarted1+generatestarted2+generatestarted3+generatestarted4+generatestarted5+generatestarted6))
    print(generatestarted)
    savenumbers = open("TelstraPhoneNumbers.txt","a").write(generatestarted+"\n")
elif carrier == "2":
    for j in range(Number2):
     generatestarted1 = random.choice(Optus)
     generatestarted2 = random.choice(gentype)
     generatestarted3 = random.choice(gentype)
     generatestarted4 = random.choice(gentype)
     generatestarted5 = random.choice(gentype)
     generatestarted6 = random.choice(gentype)
     generatestarted = ("+61"+generatestarted1+generatestarted2+generatestarted3+generatestarted4+generatestarted5+generatestarted6)
    print(generatestarted)
    savenumbers = open("OptusPhoneNumbers.txt","a").write(generatestarted+"\n")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What is the question you are trying to ask? Thank you for posting parts of your code, but, as programmers, we have to assume that the code you wrote is the code you want, unless you can describe some other functionality that the code doesn't have.

Comment: Hey bro my question is why is the program not accepting user input on the amount of numbers wanting to be generated as this code worked for me when the output was random but since i have incorporated a carrier choice it wont validate the amount wanting to be generated

Comment: How do you know that `the program not accepting user input on the amount of numbers ...`? It looks like it to me from the screen shot of the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simply a case of indentation. Your `print(generatestarted)` statement is outside the for loop. Python relies on indentation to segregate code blocks, and by looking at the code you have pasted, assuming you pasted it it as is, will only show the last number that was generated. By copying your code to my Python editor, I was able to reproduce your issue, and simply indenting `print(generatestarted)` with a single space solved the probelm:

```
for i in range(Number1):
    generatestarted1 = random.choice(Telstra)
    generatestarted2 = random.choice(gentype)
    generatestarted3 = random.choice(gentype)
    generatestarted4 = random.choice(gentype)
    generatestarted5 = random.choice(gentype)
    generatestarted6 = random.choice(gentype)
    generatestarted = ("+61"+generatestarted1+generatestarted2+generatestarted3+generatestarted4+generatestarted5+generatestarted6)
    print(generatestarted)
savenumbers = open("TelstraPhoneNumbers.txt","a").write(generatestarted+"\n")
```

Output:

```
How Many Numbers Do You Want To Generate: 2
---------------------------------------------
+61490902124
+61497956859
```

Comment: Thank you bro i cant believe it was a simple mistake like this will read my code carefully in the future once again thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your code, your problem is arising with the for loop you wrote, specifically the fact that

```
print(generatestarted)
```

is outside of your for-loop, causing only 1 number to be printed.
I would also advise that you revise this line of code:

```
generatestarted2 = random.choice(gentype)
generatestarted3 = random.choice(gentype)
generatestarted4 = random.choice(gentype)
generatestarted5 = random.choice(gentype)
generatestarted6 = random.choice(gentype)
```

as it may be slightly repetitive and when simplified can be easier to read. Hope this helps!